# Does reference of any component available before even rendering it at least once?

Tags: react-native, reference

Lets say I a have `FlatList` component as follows,

```
 <FlatList
    ref={ref => this.flatListRef = ref}
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderLeaveRequests(item, index)}
    keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
    onEndReached={this.loadMore}
 />
```

I Want `FlatList` to go to some particular item based on `offset` and I achieved like follows,

```
 componentWillMount() {
     this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({ offset: scrollPosition, animated: false });
 }
```

If you observe I am calling `scrollToOffset` in `componentWillMount` which means before rendering the component. Here my doubt is how come reference of `FlatList` is available before rendering it.

Does reference of any component available before even rendering it at least once?

Answer (score 0):

No, because you assign your ref in the render, this isn't avalaible before rendering.
Use componentDidMount instead